# SQL: How compare cells from different tables?

Tags: sql, compare, rows

I have two tables - band and band2. Band:

[image: band table]

and band2:

[image]

The columns are equals. I'm using Access 2010. I want to SELECT rows WHERE band.Kampas<>band2.Kampas, but there isn't primary key so I can't use  JOIN operation. 
Maybe someone has an idea?

The answer:

[image]

Only in these rows band.Kampas<>band2.Kampas.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don`t you use cross join? see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

Comment: You should also fix your design. Two tables with identical columns doesn't sound right

Comment: As a_horse_with_no_name said, your design is flawed if you have two similar tables but not only that, tables **with no primary key**. In which case you do not have two tables but two heaps of data. Fix the design first and it will probably make it easier to get the result you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b2.*
FROM band2 b2
WHERE b2.kampas NOT IN (SELECT b1.kampas
                        FROM band b1 
                        WHERE b1.kampas IS NOT NULL)
  AND b2.kampas IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Juronis: what exactly do you mean with that? Do you get an error? Wrong result?

Comment: @Juronis: what exactly do you mean with "empty"? No rows? Or rows where all column values are NULL?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly this is what you want:

```
Select * from band where kampas not in (select kampas from band2)
union
Select * from band2 where kampas not in (select kampas from band)
```

EDIT. Ok, might be that not in doesn't work in Access. It looks like this could work, though:

```
Select * from band2 where not exists (select * from band where band.kampas = band2.kampas)
```

This find a selection in the inner select where kampas's match and we want to pick those band2 lines that returns an empty selection in the inner select.

If you want to do this two-way (i.e. also find from band) just use union like I did in the first attempt.

Comment: It's work. Thank you. But if I want add more conditions. Select * from band2 where not exists (select * from band where band.kampas = band2.kampas AND band.Aukstis = band2.Aukstis). I think it is correct, but doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to AND or OR those fields? If you AND you will only select (in the outer select) rows where both fields match. What would you want as the output in your extended query?

Comment: I want to get rows from band2 where band.kampas != band2 and band.galia != band2.galia. I have changed a band2.galia cell.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select * 
from Band as B1 
inner join Band2 as B2 
on B1.Stotis = B2.Stotis
where B1.Kampas <> B2.Kampas
```

Comment: Columns B1.Stotis and B2.Stotis are not equals

Comment: I notice that the differewnce seems to be that there is a number after the 'Stotis' in the Band table. Is that consistent?